# Div change length% when clicking another element

Tags: jquery, click

https://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/3anktzd6/3/

Essentially I'm tying to make it so when you click the .clickable div, it subtracts the width of .meter by 15%.

So every time I click the .clickable div it makes .meter 15% narrower in width.

```
$('.clickable').bind('click', function () {
var amount;


$(".meter").css("background-color", "yellow");
$(".meter").css("width", amount=amount - 15);


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the jQuery "-=X%" css convention for this, it will make your life easier.

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".meter").css("width", "-=15%");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3anktzd6/4/

Comment: Thank you! I meant to ask this earlier, but is there a way to alert("zero percent") once it reaches 0? or alert once it reaches 45 then alert something different when it reaches 30 I've been trying but can't get it

Comment: @user18815 You can calculate the width percentage by using the parent elements width and use it however you'd like. Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3anktzd6/10/